# how to control what voiceover reads when developing a website

Tags: html, voiceover, talkback

I am designing a website for people with visual impairments with focus on mobile usage. For now I have some simple buttons like "play", "stop" and voice over reads what I have put between `<button></button>` tags. However, I want to make it as precise as possible because older people might be using it as well and include something like "press this button to play recording" but then it becomes really long and the button just looks awful. Is there a way to include this information in a button without having to display this text on a website?

```
<button>Play</button>
```

I would like to have a button like this, but so the voice over reads a hidden tag like "press this button to play recording". How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute) for this:

```css
.help-text {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<button 
  id="play-button" 
  aria-describedby="play-button-explanation"
>
  Play
</button>
<span 
  id="play-button-explanation" 
  class="help-text"
>
  Press this button to play recording.
</span>
```

When I use VoiceOver on this button, I get:

> Play, button. Press this button to play recording. You are currently on a button ...

This would work even if the element wasn't being displayed, but I think it's good to have that context for people who *can* read it, too.

Comment: Great, it does what I wanted however now the voice reader reads the span tag as well, so in result it reads it twice, is there maybe an option to hide it?

Comment: Aria-hidden will tell screen reads not to use it. Careful using this it might make them not read it at all.

Comment: No, it's fine to use `aria-hidden` on the <span>.  It will prevent you from being able to swipe to it with VoiceOver, which is what @Marcel wants, **and** it will still be read as the description of the button.  That's part of the "accessible name computation" - https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2 - see step 2A

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intending to display the label text on the screen, you can use [aria-label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute)

```
<button 
  id="play-button" 
  aria-label="Press this button to play recording"
>
  Play
</button>
```